# Count vs select query performance in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

We have a PosgtreSQL DB table with lots of data. I wonder what type of query is faster / has a better performance and why?

1. `select * from table`
2. `select count (*) from table`

Comment: Different results. Choose the one you need.

Comment: Two different questions that give you different results. Why do you even care about the difference in time needed to get these different results?

Comment: It's possible to use them for the same purpose because clients tend to expose the [`ROW_COUNT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) variable. In the first case the app can read the row count associated with the result, in the second it can read the result. If you need both the count and the actual data, the first query can get them both at once. If you only need the row count, the contents of the table would just waste IO, weigh and slow things down, so `count(*)` is enough.

Comment: I know what they do, I just need to count at first and later, in some rare cases, use the result data. That's why I wonder if doing `count` at first and then `select` is better than doing `select` at the beggining. If the `select` has a worse performance, I'll use `count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both queries do iterate over the entire table, the first query will perform generally much worse at an application level versus the second one.  This is because the `select *` query will need to send the entire table across the network to the application which is executing the query.  The `count(*)` query, on the other hand, only needs to send across a single integer count.

Comment: In addition to the network time, query #2 could skip the heap and count entries in the index, something that is much faster.